# Apache Spark standalone mode: number of cores

Tags: multithreading, deployment, apache-spark

I'm trying to understand the basics of Spark internals and Spark documentation for submitting applications in local mode says for `spark-submit --master` setting:

> local[K]  Run Spark locally with K worker threads (ideally, set this to
>   the number of cores on your machine).
>
> local[*]  Run Spark locally with
>   as many worker threads as logical cores on your machine.

Since all the data is stored on a single local machine, it does not benefit from distributed operations on `RDD`s.

How does it benefit and what internally is going on when Spark utilizes several logical cores?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The system will allocate additional threads for processing data.  Despite being limited to a single machine, it can still take advantage of the high degree of parallelism available in modern servers.

If you have a reasonable sized data set, say something with a dozen partitions, you can measure the time it takes to use local[1] vs local[n] (where n is the number of cores in your machine). You can also see the difference in utilization of your machine.  If you only have one core designated for use, it will only use 100% of one core (plus some extra for garbage collection).  If you have 4 cores, and specify local[4], it will use 400% of a core (4 cores).  And execution time can be significantly shortened (although not typically by 4x).

Comment: Two comments. First, for streaming, you have to allocate a dedicated thread to each input source, plus at least one for the main processing, so if you're listening to one socket you'll need at least "local[2]". Second, sometimes a single thread will be faster than multiple threads if the overhead outweighs the benefits.

Comment: That's interesting - I did experiment at have seen a speed-up, not linear though. Suppose I create a job with single RDD that fits machine memory. Is it right that RDDs would not be partitioned? Then how operations are parallelized to several cores?

Comment: you can repartition RDDs into any number of partitions you want.  By default, if you load an RDD from HDFS it will have a number of partitions equal to the number of blocks it used in HDFS. If you load a file from the local file system, you can specify the number partitions you want it to be split into.  By experimentation, you can match this number to what is most efficent; I would suggest trying 1x, 2x, or 4x the number of cores your computer has.